# MariaDB loop not displaying results of query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, adminer

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ud.UserID), COUNT(DISTINCT ud.ProductID)
FROM users_data AS ud
    JOIN products AS t ON t.ID = ud.ProductID
WHERE ud.UserID = '3'
```

Which results in:

```
COUNT(ud.UserID)    COUNT(DISTINCT ud.ProductID)
519                 425
```

When I try to include in a while or for loop:

```
DELIMITER //

SET @i = 0;
FOR i IN 1..10
DO SELECT COUNT(ud.UserID), COUNT(DISTINCT ud.ProductID)
  FROM users_data AS ud
    JOIN products AS t ON t.ID = ud.ProductID
  WHERE ud.UserID = (i)
END FOR
//
```

I get no output other than:

```
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected.
```

Is there something else I'm misssing? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use a `loop`?  This is much better to do as a simple query:

```
SELECT ud.UserId, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT ud.ProductID)
FROM users_data ud 
GROUP BY ud.UserID;
```

If you want specific users, you can use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ud.UserId, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT ud.ProductID)
FROM users_data ud 
WHERE ud.UserId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
GROUP BY ud.UserID;
```

Note:  I don't think the `JOIN` is necessary.

Comment: My intention was to iterate through a range of users (like 1-10). When I try your example it seems to take a very long time (I'm still waiting over 10 minutes). It's a huge database, so if there's a way to quickly return a range of users that's going to work better, thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, that works much better! (I ended up using `BETWEEN 1 AND 10` instead of `1, 2, 3...` because I'll need to specify different ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer to the question asked is in the definition of `DO`.  It is defined to perform the query, then throw away the results.